# Can't find element by Xpath in Selenium no matter what I try

Tags: python, selenium

This is my first attempt at Selenium, I'm attempting to create a program that copy's my clipboard and pastes it into a soundcloud downloader website, but i am not able to find an element after changing pages. This is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://scdownloader.io/')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(45)

# driver.implicitly_wait(60)
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/div/input") #text box
box.click()
box.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')

nxt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/button") #convert button
nxt.click()

driver.refresh()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

dl = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='conversionForm']/form/button")
dl.click()
```

The issue is with finding dl, my attempt at solving it was attempting a refresh, trying the other xpath addresses found using the selenium addon in chrome, and trying to switch to an iframe, but I'm honestly not sure if there is an iframe.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: provide html code it helps to find xpath

Comment: you can check if there is an iframe in you page by simply `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")))`.

Answer (score 1):

The page you are trying to access doesn't contain any iframe. You don't need to switch to an iframe to click the download button.

The code you have provided is pasting your clipboard into the input field and clicks on the convert button. Clicking on the convert button loads a different URL which doesn't show the convert button. But your `dl` variable contains the convert button element reference. You've used the XPath of the convert button again for `dl` variable. Once you have clicked on the convert button it is not visible for the next page. That is why you can't find the button.

Also, use explicit waits instead of the implicit wait.

The following code will print the download link. It will print 'Invalid link' if the posted link is invalid and there is no download link. The `result` variable contains a list. It is for checking if the result is visible or not without getting any exception. To get the download link button `resutl[0]` is used.

**Try This:**

```py
driver.get('https://scdownloader.io/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='conversionForm']/form/div/input")))#text box
box.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')

nxt = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='conversionForm']/form/button")))#convert button
nxt.click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='result']")))

result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='searchboxholder']//a")

if(len(result)>0):
    print(result[0].get_attribute("href"))
else:
    print("Invalid link")
```

To use WebDriverWait you have to import the followings:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the code you provided does provide me the  download link token, however I don't understand how I actually download the the file. If i use `result[0].click()` it opens the token link, but a download doesn't actually start like it would if I clicked the button.

Comment: You have to give the browser time to start and download the file. `result[0].click()` does start download. How to handle file download with selenium is a different question altogether.